# Magento Child Theme Creation Issue

Tags: magento, themes, fallback

I've a fresh installation of Magento ver 1.9.1.0 on localhost. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide) closely to create a child theme of Magento responsive theme.

I've followed all steps clearly. I've created Magento directory structure, using this approach

```
[Magento Directory]/app/design/frontend/{package_name}/{theme_name}/etc
```

and created theme.xml file there. As can be seen 
[image]

Exact location of the theme.xml file is:

```
[Magento Directory]/app/design/frontend/tutsplus/vstyle/etc
```

as my package name is 'tutsplus' and theme name is 'vstyle'. I've also correctly enabled this theme from admin panel. As can be seen in below screenshot:

[image]

The code of theme.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>
```

Can someone point out what am I missing?

Comment: can you tell me what is the issue

Comment: Page appears broken, with no style.

Comment: On the tutorial I'm following it is written:

 If styles.css is loading from a path similar to the following, theme.xml is most likely not loading.

`http://www.example.com/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css`

This is precisely the problem I'm facing

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. But here I had put comments `<!-- -->` in `theme.xml`. I had to just strip them.

Your file may be unreadable or corrupted.

Comment: This was my problem as well, the [tutorial I followed](http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes/) had the first line as a comment, removing it fixed it the theme.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same issue here but here's how I solved it.

In addition to adding the package name and template name at System > Configuration > Design, you need to go to System > Design and add your new theme there too.

[system > design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaxQ3.png)

[add package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrWOq.png)

Comment: That worked. I had to go to System > Design then Add design Changes and choose the new child theme and only the start date then save.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen it already, check out http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide.

The guide has additional information you'll need to get started.

Comment: I've not only read it, but also followed it step by step, as you can see from the steps I've explained in the question. I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: Another interesting thing to note is that even when I created new local.xml file in layout directory that also doesn't seem to be working. In fact I think no xml file is working. While the phtml files under template directory are just working fine.

Comment: @GnMcVey 's Suggestion worked. Check my comment there. BTW disable all cache in your local or flush cache after saving the design change

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if the theme.xml file was formatted like this:

```
<theme>
    <parent>
        packagename/actualtheme
    </parent>
</theme>
```

It will not work. It needs to be formatted:

```
<theme>
    <parent>packagename/actualtheme</parent>
</theme>
```

Not sure why; maybe someone with more advanced knowledge could comment.